# VHDL how do i iterate over all elements in a record

Tags: vhdl

Is there any way that I can iterate over all elements for a record type? for simplicity, let's say all element types in the record are std_logic.

for example:

```
type bar is record 
   bar1 : std_logic;
   bar2 : std_logic;
   bar3 : std_logic;
end record;
```

How do I (is it even possible) to access the element of any arbitrary record type?

(I understood that with the new VHDL we will have introspection)

With VHDL2008 is there any way I can use some attribute to access an element and assuming that we know the type of the element beforehand, then how can we iterate over this record?

Comment: Tricky relates there is no VHDL [record introspection](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/RecordIntrospection). A record subtype doesn't depend on the number of elements unlike an array type. The subtype of a record element of an array composite type can be found by introspection. Two different record types can't be closely related. The number of elements isn't unknown, nor are element types. This question's example isn't compelling.

Comment: I think there may be ways of doing this. Not with a record but with a custom container type. Can you give some more details about your use case?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot iterate over a record (with any current or future versions). It would make little sense as you cannot take a different action based on a type. Iteration can only be done over an array.

Comment: This statement is now false. VHDL 2019 allows record reflection.

Comment: It depends from what point in time. Afaik, no tools currently support the VHDL 2019 'reflect attribute (or much of 2019 for that matter).

Comment: Well yeah, definitely not for synthesis. However, RovieraPRO has a lot of support for it right now. Not completely, but they enough to use the main new features and have been extremely responsive to fixing bugs.